# Terminological conflict in tensor calculus

Tags: terminology, covariance

In the wiki article (I know, not alaways the MOST trusted source, and I’m also not sure how to add the link) for covariance and contravariance of vectors, near the beginning a paragraph starts by talking about James Joseph Sylvester and talks about how he named them from properties of functors. It then says:

*unfortunately, it is the lower-index objects (covectors) that generically have pullbacks, which are contravariant, while the upper-index objects (vectors) instead have pushforwards, which are covariant. This terminological conflict may be avoided by calling contravariant functors "cofunctors"—in accord with the "covector" terminology, and continuing the tradition of treating vectors as the concept and covectors as the 
coconcept*

The linked wikis didn’t exactly help clarify. For some reason this originally made sense (I think because I assumed vectors had lower indices but I can't remember if I thought there'd be a reason for that) and somehow it doesn’t any more now that I’ve thought of it more attentively and I can show that the covariant basis is covariant, etc. The article however says this is otherwise, that vectors are covariant and covectors are contravariant, but I can't see why. I can see though how this thing with the "co"s could be a little confusing. How did/can this terminological conflict arise and what is meant by calling contravariant functors cofunctors to avoid it? I've never (yet) heard those terms used. Thanks in advance for any answers :)

Comment: This might work better on hsm.se or physics.se.

Comment: I don't even care about their application in physics, and it seems these things all have lovely pure math definitions...

Comment: @BenjamiThoburn I understand that, but if you want to understand why terminology has gotten inconsistent or messy you can't always count on mathematicians to explain it. Your question needs more than us copy-pasting the same definitions that tripped you up.